# I want to create a bug whenever my build pipeline fails in azure devops. And i want to have it configured for a particular branch

Tags: azure-devops, devops, branch, tfs-workitem, build-pipeline

I want to have my build pipeline configured such a way that when ever my pipeline fails there is a bug created for the same. I cannot find an option to select this configuration for a particular branch. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a bug whenever my build pipeline fails in azure devops. And i want to have it configured for a particular branch

There is an option [Create a work item on failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops#create-a-work-item-on-failure) on the pipeline Options tab.

If the build pipeline fails, it can automatically create a work item to track getting the problem fixed.

But we could not configurate it for a particular branch for this option, but we could create a new pipeline with trigger filter Branch specification:

[image]

In this case, only the particular branch build failed, it will create a bug.